# How can I modify style from buttons in xctk xceed wizard?

Tags: c#, wpf, wizard, toolkit, xceed

I'm trying to modify the style of the back, finish, cancel and next buttons at the bottom of the xctk:Wizard. I have tried to do it by modifying the style of the xctk:Wizard but nothing seems to work. I would like to make those buttons bigger. I'm using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.WizardPage.

Since I don't have direct access to those buttons (or at least I don't know how to access them) an easy task like this is making me sweat hard

This is an example of what I'm trying to do in order to accomplish my goal.

```
         <xctk:Wizard.Style>
            <Style TargetType="xctk:Wizard">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                        Value="Bold"/>
            </Style>
        </xctk:Wizard.Style>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an implicit `Button` style to the Wizard's `Resources` property:

```
<xctk:Wizard>
    <xctk:Wizard.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
        </Style>
    </xctk:Wizard.Resources>
    ...
</xctk:Wizard>
```